# How can I make my footer underlap the main content area with CSS positioning?

Tags: css, positioning, footer, overlap, absolute

Here's a link to the page I'm having a problem making:

http://willhost.webs.com/First%20CSS%20Page/Homepage%20Actual.html

I want the green footer to vertically underlap the grey content box by 39px. I can do this by setting the footer position property to 'relative' and entering a top value of '39px' (and increasing z-index of grey box) but that still leaves a space where the footer is meant to go in the normal flow - I don't wan't that.

So it would seem setting the footer to absolute positioning is the answer. But when I do so, the footer disappears off the screen?!

I only started web coding a month ago so please forgive me if this is a noobish question.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers, Will W

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `margin-top`

```
#footer {
    background: #95D704;
    font: normal 13px 'Museo Sans 100';
    height: 97px;
    margin-top: 39px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You're help is invaluable to a clueless 18 year old :)